# Как можно передать данные между Sidebar и скриптом, не изменяя код

Tags: google-apps-script

- Как добавить в боковую панель пользовательскую информацию без правки кода скрипта?
- Возможно ли выполнить код на сервере, который отправляет пользователь? Опять же, без правки кода скрипта.

Comment: Куда добавлять информацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без редактирования скриптов можно создавать/получать новую информацию двумя способами: на сервере и на клиенте.

## Исполнение произвольного кода на сервере

Вы можете выполнять eval() на стороне сервера. Просто передайте код как строку

### На сервере

```
function execute(code) {
    var wrap = Utilities.formatString('(function(global_scope){%s})(this)', code);
    eval(wrap);
}
```

### На клиенте

```
google.script.run.execute('Logger.log("Bingo!")');
```

### Рабочий пример

https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/0c94d9480749453d180e2c8cb05051ad

Можно сделать копию и запустить как дополнение.

## Формирование данных на клиенте

Делится на два основных случая:

- Преобразование выдачи (синхронное выполнение)
- Клиентский ИПП (асинхронное выполнение)

В [лучших практиках](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) рекомендуется использовать [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

```
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showThings)
    .getLotsOfThings();
});
```

Подробнее в статье [Как передать данные клиенту?](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/fd0ffc5436bf49b1d831)